# Is there any way to run doom on ubuntu?

Tags: software-center, games, elementary

I want to run doom on my elementary OS (ubuntu derivative), any ideas on how could i do it?

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq), Ask Ubuntu provides support for [recognized Ubuntu flavors](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives). Your question may be welcome at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 7):

You don't specify what Doom game you mean, so I presume you mean the old original Doom created by ID Software.

since its a DOS game. You need a DOS emulator.

Install `dosbox` from Ubuntu Software Center or with the `apt-get install dosbox` command from the terminal.  It will allow you to run most DOS games.

After starting dosbox you need to mount the folder where you have Doom stored on your computer.

For example if I have Doom stored in `/home/larry/downloads/doom`, in `dosbox` you would have to write:

```
mount c /home/larry/downloads/doom
```

to mount the doom folder directly to the virtaul `C:` drive.

If you want to run the game in Multiplayer over network (Yes you can run it over the Internet as well) check out the [documentation](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Connectivity) Its Much easier than in the old days.

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler way to play an original Doom clone, first I install `prboom` via terminal (`sudo apt-get install prboom`) and then I launch it by typing `prboom` in the terminal.

**2018 Edit**: Use [`prboom-plus`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/prboom-plus/) fork instead:

```
sudo apt install prboom-plus
```

Comment: prdoom is not the original Doom. its a clone.

Comment: prboom is derived from the original Doom source code. So it's not a clone, it's a fork.

Comment: what is the difference between prboom, prboom-plus and the original Doom?